# How to modify the value of a pandas dataframe "cell" from within a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, function, dataframe

Why will this work in Pyhon 3:

```
for i in range(0, len(df.index) ):
    df.loc[i,["Processed"]] =  "YES"
```

and why wont this work:

```
def mylargeprocess(SomeData,Processed):
    Processed = "YES"

for i in range(0, len(df.index) ):
    mylargeprocess(df.loc[i,["SomeData"]],df.loc[i,["Processed"]])
```

I am pretty sure it has something to do with strings being inmutable, but I would still like to understand the diference betweeen those codes.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

`pd.DataFrame.loc` is used both for **setting** and for **accessing** values. In this first example, you are setting values. In the second example, you are only accessing data. First you pass a `pd.DataFrame` object to a function, then assign the string "Yes" to the variable `Processed`.

You can debug what's happening yourself by using `print`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['this', 'is'], ['a', 'test']],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2'])

def process(df_in):
    df_in = 'hello'
    print(df_in)  # you'll see 'hello' printed twice, no assignment happens

for i in range(len(df.index)):
    process(df.loc[i, ['col2']])
```